# Add & Print from List using Scanner

Tags: java

I am creating a project that allows a user to create, delete or display bank accounts and  to deposit, withdraw or print transactions.

I don't know how to deposit, withdraw, print transactions using the scanner when the user provides the account id.

**main:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    BankProcess bankProcess = new BankProcess();
    TransactionProcess transactionProcess = new TransactionProcess();

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

    int input = 0;
    int selection = 0;

    while (input == 0) {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Please choose one of the following: ");
      System.out.println("[1] Create an account");
      System.out.println("[2] Print all existing accounts");
      System.out.println("[3] Delete an account");
      System.out.println("[4] Deposit");
      System.out.println("[5] Withdraw");
      System.out.println("[6] Print transactions");
      System.out.println("[0] Exit");
      selection = scan.nextInt();

      switch (selection) {

        case 0:
          System.out.println("Exit Successful");
          System.exit(0);

        case 1:
          System.out.println("'[1] Create an account' has been selected.");
          System.out.print("Account Id: ");
          int accountId = scan.nextInt();
          scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Name: ");
          String holderName = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Address: ");
          String holderAddress = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Opening Balance: ");
          double openingBalance = scan.nextDouble();

          System.out.print("Open Date: ");
          String openDate = scan.next();

          bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountId, holderName, openingBalance, holderAddress, openDate);
          bank.setAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));

          System.out.println("Successfully Added.");
          break;

        case 2:
          System.out.println("'[2] Display all existing accounts' has been selected");
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
          bank.getAccounts().forEach((i, b) - > System.out.println(b));
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
          break;

        case 3:
          System.out.println("[3] Delete an account has been selected");
          System.out.println("Enter the account ID: ");
          bank.removeAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));
          break;

        case 4:
          System.out.println("[4] Deposit has been selected");

          break;

        case 5:
          System.out.println("[5] Withdraw has been selected");

          break;

        case 6:
          System.out.println("[6] Print Transaction has been selected");

          break;

        default:
          System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

      }
    }
  }
```

**class Bank**

```
public class Bank {

  private TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts = new TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > ();

  public TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > getAccounts() {
    return bankAccounts;
  }
  public void setAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }

  public void removeAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }
}
```

**class BankProcess**

```
public class BankProcess {
  // return the  Updated list of BankAccounts
  public TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > openNewAccount(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts, BankAccount bankAccount) {
    //Get the List of existing bank Accounts then add the new BankAccount to it.
    bankAccounts.put(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
    return bankAccounts;
  }

  public TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > removeAccount(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts, BankAccount bankAccount) {
    bankAccounts.remove(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
    return bankAccounts;
  }
}
```

**class BankAccount**

```
public class BankAccount {
  private int accountId;
  private String holderName;
  private String holderAddress;
  private String openDate;
  private double currentBalance;

  private List < Transaction > transactions = new ArrayList < Transaction > ();

  //Provide Blank Constructor
  public BankAccount() {}

  //Constructor with an arguments.
  public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam, double currentBalance, String holderAdd, String openDate) {
    this.accountId = accountNum;
    this.holderName = holderNam;
    this.holderAddress = holderAdd;
    this.openDate = openDate;
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
  }

  // Always Provide Setter and Getters
  public int getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
  }
  public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
  }
  public String getHolderName() {
    return holderName;
  }
  public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
    this.holderName = holderName;
  }
  public String getHolderAddress() {
    return holderAddress;
  }
  public void setHolderAddress(String holderAddress) {
    this.holderAddress = holderAddress;
  }
  public String getOpenDate() {
    return openDate;
  }
  public void setOpenDate(String openDate) {
    this.openDate = openDate;
  }
  public double getCurrentBalance() {
    return currentBalance;
  }
  public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
  }

  public List < Transaction > getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
  }

  public void setTransactions(List < Transaction > transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "\nAccount number: " + accountId + "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
  }
}
```

**class Transaction**

```
public class Transaction {
  private int transactionId;
  private String transactionType;
  private double transactionAmount;
  private double moneyBeforeTransaction;
  private double moneyAfterTransaction;

  public Transaction() {}

  public Transaction(int transactionId, String transactionType, double transactionAmount, double moneyBeforeTransaction) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    this.moneyBeforeTransaction = moneyBeforeTransaction;
  }

  public int getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
  }

  public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
  }

  public String getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
  }

  public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
  }

  public double getTransactionAmount() {
    return transactionAmount;
  }

  public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
  }

  public double getMoneyBeforeTransaction() {
    return moneyBeforeTransaction;
  }

  public void setMoneyBeforeTransaction(double moneyBeforeTransaction) {
    this.moneyBeforeTransaction = moneyBeforeTransaction;
  }

  public double getMoneyAfterTransaction() {
    return moneyAfterTransaction;
  }

  public void setMoneyAfterTransaction(double moneyAfterTransaction) {
    this.moneyAfterTransaction = moneyAfterTransaction;
  }

  //Override the toString() method of String ? 
  public String toString() {
    return "Transaction ID : " + this.transactionId +
      " Transaction Type : " + this.transactionType +
      " Transaction Amount : " + this.transactionAmount +
      " Money Before Transaction : " + this.moneyBeforeTransaction +
      " Money After Transaction : " + this.moneyAfterTransaction;
  }

}
```

**class TransactionProcess**

```
public class TransactionProcess {

  //Always Provide another class for process.
  //Pass the bankAccount of the user
  public void deposit(BankAccount bankAccount, double depositAmount) {
    //Get the CurrentBalance
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();

    //First Argument : set the Id of transaction
    //Second Argument : set the Type of Transaction
    //Third Argument : set the TransactionAmount 
    //Fourth Argument : set the Balance Before the transaction (for record purposes)
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Deposit", depositAmount, currentBalance);

    if (depositAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
      //Set the updated or transacted balance of bankAccount.
      bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance + depositAmount);
      //then set the MoneyAfterTransaction
      transaction.setMoneyAfterTransaction(bankAccount.getCurrentBalance());
      //after the transaction add it to the list of Transaction of bankAccount
      bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);
    }

  }

  // Explanation same as above
  public void withdraw(BankAccount bankAccount, double withdrawAmount) {
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction(bankAccount.getTransactions().size(), "Withdraw", withdrawAmount, currentBalance);

    if (withdrawAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
    } else {
      if (currentBalance < withdrawAmount) {
        System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
      } else {
        bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance - withdrawAmount);
        transaction.setMoneyAfterTransaction(bankAccount.getCurrentBalance());
        bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add more details and perhaps reduce the amount of code. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Instead of pasting your whole project, please paste relevant code and exception or error you are getting.

Comment: I am having problems with the transaction section of the project. How can I create a transaction (Deposit, withdraw and print all transaction) in the scanner. The user will input a accountid which has been created and will deposit or withdraw the amount. I don't know how I could lay this out in the mainsample class.

Comment: That's a bit of code, but am I right to suspect it only runs once? `while (input == 0)` is problematic. You do initialize it to 0, but then you have 0 as the exit #, I also didn't see anywhere you make sure that's the case (maybe missed it?) before looping. So, the only way it seems to continue the process is choose to exit which obviously "does not compute."

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I didn't really understand what you know.

Comment: Look at the code in your main(). Your `while` condition isn't going to work. Follow your code line by line if the user enters 0 the first time, then follow it again if the user doesn't enter 0 the first time. You'll see the user will *not* be able to exit in the former, and won't be able to continue with additional operations if 0 is *not* entered in the latter. IOW, you have a logical paradox; so-to-speak.

Comment: how can that be fixed?

Comment: `int selection=-1; while(selection!=0)` at the beginning. You don't need `input`. Then you can also remove the *switch-case* `case 0` because when the user inputs a `0`, the `selection` variable will be `0` and thus the `while-loop` will stop (the program will stop)

Comment: OK Thank you. What about my original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations like *deposit* or *withdraw* work almost the same way, so let's concentrate on *deposit* for now.

You already have the appropriate switch-case for that:

```
case 4: {
     // deposit
     break;
}
```

(by the way: the braces `{` and `}` are not mandatory here, they just help to isolate the code, so that it is easier to read)

Anyway; For deposing money on a bank account you need the account number first and then you need to get the account from the bank

```
 case 4: {
     int accountNumber =  scan.nextInt();  // user types account number
     TreeMap <Integer, BankAccount> bankAccounts = bank.getAccounts();  // bank returns all accounts (this is quite an insecure operation, it would be better to add a method to the bank class that returns only one account when passing the accountNumber
     BankAccount bankAccount = bankAccounts.get(accountNumber);
     break;
}
```

Using the method `bank.getAccounts` is not a good design here, as the method will return *all* accounts from the bank. It would be better to have a method in your class `Bank` that returns a single account.

```
public class Bank{
  // ...
  public BankAccount getAccount(Integer accountNumber){
     return bankAccounts.get(accountNumber);
  }
}
```

Because this will encapsulate the logic to retrieve one account to the `Bank` class. There you can also add some error handling logic, e.g. when the account number is not valid.

So, at this point you have the user's account and you know the user wants to deposit some money. You only have to ask how much he wants to deposit. Use the Scanner again to let the user type in an amount.

Now that you have your `BankAccount` and the amount you need to make a `Transaction` or better a `TransactionProcess`

```
 TransactionProcess transactionProcess = new TransactionProcess();  // use the standard constructor to create an empty transactionProcess
 transactionProcess.deposit(bankAccount, amount);
```

If I understand your program correctly, the method `deposit` will already use the user's BankAccount and add the money while creating a Transaction for the account. Am I correct? Then you are actually finished here.

Put that code together for `switch-chase` 4 and if it works use a similar logic to implement `withdraw`.

I hope this helps!

**// Edit //** to answer your other question, this is what I had in mind:

in your `BankAccount` class add a method like this one:

```
public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction){
   if(transactions.size() >= 6){  // test if the list has 6 or more transactions saved 
      transactions.remove(0);     // if so, then remove the first (it's the oldest)
   }
   transactions.add(transaction); // the new transaction is always added, no matter how many other transactions there are already in the list
}
```

This is just an example, but I think you should be able to control the amount of transactions per Bank account like this. In addition you can now simplify the call: have a look at the last line of your `deposit` method in your `TransactionProcess` class. There you call

```
bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);  // takes the bank account, retrieves the list of transactions from the bank account and adds a transaction to the list
```

with the new method `addTransaction` you could now write it like this instead:

```
bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
```

Much cleaner, don't you think? And now you can put all your logic for managing and adding transactions in that new method :)

Comment: I understand the concept you're telling me here but when I try to implement it, there's error like for case 4, it's saying the variable is already defined. Is my transaction and transactionprocess classes laid out properly?

Comment: For transactions, I will need to store only the last 6 transactions and print it out. Would I need to change my transactionprocess completely for this?

Comment: No, you don't have to change much. Right now you add a transaction like this: `bankAccount.getTransactions().add(transaction);`. It's the same as with the `getAccount()` I told you earlier - don't get the whole list only for adding one item. Create a new method in your class `BankAccount` that adds a new transaction. Something like this: `addTransaction(transaction)`. And in that method you add the transaction to the list. To limit the number of transactions in the list, you can remove the first transaction before adding a new one `if(transactions.size()>=6){transactions.remove(0);}

Comment: I fully understand the last code. But confused about where the other code should go.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the example method that should help you to limit the number of transactions. With that method you will only hold 6 transactions per account in the list. So for printing them you just have to iterate through the list (`for..`) and print out every single transaction

Comment: How would I implement the print transaction method into case 6. I want the user to input the account ID then it will print the list.